# Не получатся замапить DMA буфер в Linux из userspace

Tags: c++, c, linux

В модуле/драйвере выделяется память для DMA транзакций через ioctl():

```
kbuf = dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, CRU_DMA_BUF0_SIZE, &dma_handle, 0);
```

далее возвращается физический адрес в user space:

```
ret = put_user(virt_to_phys(kbuf), (unsigned long __user *)arg/*адрес переменной dma_buf в приложении*/);
```

в приложении пытаюсь замапить эту область памяти:

```
int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
if(mmap_dma = (unsigned long*) mmap(NULL, CRU_DMA_BUF0_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, dma_buf))
printf("Can't mapping DMA buffer\n");
```

*#define        CRU_DMA_BUF0_SIZE    (0x00800000)*

на удалённой машине получаю в dmesg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут где-то писали, что ядерную память с какой-то версии ядра запретили просто так шарить.

Comment: Что-то у вас не так с проверкой результата mmap, она всегда возвращает не 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут несколько проблем:

- вместо `virt_to_phys()` для памяти выделенной под ДМА, было бы правильнее использовать `dma_to_phys()` (которому отдаётся шинный адрес (из `dma_handle`) и указатель на устройство) для получения физического адреса (хотя он и будет тем же самым в большинстве случаев)
- отображение через `/dev/mem` не отработало, поскольку в большинстве штатных ядер включена защита от доступа куда попало (`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`) через этот файл и доступ даётся только к регионам шины ПиСиАй и БИОСа

Правильно подобные вопросы решаются реализацией операции `mmap` на драйвере символьного устройства, которая будет отображать те же самые физические адреса в пользовательское пространство где-то так:

```
typedef struct xxx_struct {
    struct pci_dev *pcid;
    dma_addr_t dmaaddr;
    size_t dmasize;
} xxx_t;

static int xxx_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    xxx_t *p = filp->private_data;

    vma->vm_flags |= VM_IO | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP | VM_PFNMAP;

    if (io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
            (unsigned long)dma_to_phys(&p->pcid->dev, p->dmaaddr) >> PAGE_SHIFT + vma->vm_pgoff,
            MIN(vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, p->dmasize),
            vma->vm_page_prot))
        return -EAGAIN;
    return 0;
}
```

А пользовательскому приложению остаётся лишь открыть файл и позвать `mmap()`. На английском подобное [неплохо описано здесь](http://nairobi-embedded.org/mmap_mmio_dma.html#example-mmaping-dma-allocations).